# Union of countably many sets is uncountable implies at least one of them is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that we have an unountable set. If it is written as the union of countably many sets, this should mean that at least one of these sets is uncountable.

I think that this intuitive statement can be made rigourus using the pigeonhole priniple. How hould I write down a rigorous proof?

Comment: Isnt that just contraposition of what you stated first?

You could for contradiction assume that all of the sets in the union were countable,  and then apply  the result you stated at the first line.

Comment: @Conformal, I know, but I would like to apply the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: What do you mean by the pigeonhole principle, here?  Do you mean to show that there is no injection from the larger set to the smaller?

Comment: The two assertions (countable union of countables is countable, and if a countable union is uncountable, at least one of the sets is uncountable) say exactly the same thing.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, then let me reword the question: how do I prove the second assertion without using the first one?

Comment: In the future, please don't change outright what a question is asking like that. While you were editing, I had written an answer to the original question that's now irrelevant.

Comment: @MikeHaskel When the OP edits their question, you should edit your answer.  No harm done.  Also, I don't see how the OP's edit made their question radically different.  Why doesn't your answer somehow still apply?

Comment: @L.Y: You cannot prove one without proving the other. The two results are trivially equivalent. As you probably know, there is no "constructive" proof: a weak form of the Axiom of Choice is required.

Comment: @user46944 In the end it's not really a big deal, but the original question asked to prove the result given anther one. The new question asks to prove it directly. The harm is the (admittedly small) time I spent writing an answer to the first question, which now does not apply.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why is the axiom of choice needed? You can show $\aleph_0\times\aleph_0 = \aleph_0$ by building a bijection directly, and it seems direct to see that $\aleph_0\times\aleph_0$ is an upper bound for a countable union of countable sets (in the worst case, it's a disjoint union of countably infinite sets). You may be thinking of the use of choice in showing $\kappa \times \kappa = \kappa$ for arbitrary $\kappa$.

Comment: @MikeHaskel:   Assume the sets are countably infinite, AC is needed to choose (simultaneously) a bijection from each set with $\mathbb{N}$. But needed is a slippery word, maybe it is not really *needed*, just happens to be *used* in the standard proofs. However, one can construct actual models of ZF in which a countable union of countables is not countable.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Good point. It just goes to show how ingrained choice is in the thought processes of those of us whose specializations use it as a matter of course.

Comment: For sure. There was is an entertaining example in early twentieth century mathematics, when at least one vehement (analyst) opponent of AC had (of course)  implicitly used AC in his work.  Enjoy (?) northern Indiana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the assertion that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Let $B$ be the assertion that if a countable union of sets is uncountable, then at least one of the sets is uncountable.

Assertions $A$ and $B$ are trivially equivalent. A  proof of one is (one tiny step  from) a proof of the other.

**Remark:** Each of $A$ and $B$ requires a weak version of the Axiom of Choice. There are models of ZF in which a countable union of countable sets is not necessarily countable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you can prove that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

In this case we have a countable union of sets that is uncountable. So, using the pigeonhole principle, at least one of the sets must be uncountable since there are too many elements for all of the sets to be countable

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A=\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ where $A$ is uncontable and for all $i$
$A_i$ is contable the we have a contradiction so (for the first observations in your post) so there exist some $i$ such that $A_i$ uncontable.